# How to make a REST API call from Microsoft Bot for Teams using node js?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have created a Microsoft Bot using the following documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/visual-studio-code-overview .
Now what I want to achieve is if user enters "show data" in the chat, I want to display the data which I will get from an API endpoint in JSON format.
I have tried the following code creating a new file named `getData.js` :

```
const axios = require('axios');

class getData {
    async getDataJson() {

        const config = {
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://someurl',
            headers: { 'name': 'user_name', 'token': 'token' }
        }

        let res = await axios(config);
    
        let data = res.data;
    
        return data;
    }
}

module.exports.getData = getData;
```

If this method is correct, how do I use it to send reply to the user the result data ?Also how do I populate the headers which should be the email and token generated using the SSO authentication method used in `dialog/mainDialog.js`?

Comment: You are trying to use `await` into a no-async method. Also is the constructor! You can't do that, please create a function where do the axios call like `async doCall(){ /*your call*/ }` and call this method into constructor `this.doCall()`.

Comment: Yeah actually I had updated the function.I'll add the update here.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the token from ***maindialog*** pass it as a parameter in a function.(I have a function called findintent that is where I pass the token)

```
async processStep(step) {
        console.log("Inside process step");
        if (step.result) {
            // We do not need to store the token in the bot. When we need the token we can
            // send another prompt. If the token is valid the user will not need to log back in.
            // The token will be available in the Result property of the task.
            const tokenResponse = step.result;

            // If we have the token use the user is authenticated so we may use it to make API calls.
            if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse.token) {
                    await OAuthHelpers.findIntent(step.context, tokenResponse);
               }
        } else {
            await step.context.sendActivity('We couldn\'t log you in. Please try again later.');
        }

        return await step.endDialog();
    }
```

After that try using node fetch to get the data from API.

```
async findIntent(context,tokenResponse){
let header_info = {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + tokenResponse.token
        };
let respone = await fetch("your URL",{
              method: 'GET'
              headers: header_info
});

let result = await response.json();
            console.log(result);
}
```

also refer this page https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch for more info.

Comment: what is the `processStep(step)` function and I don't want to immediately call the  `findIntent` function when the user is authorized.I want to call it if the user enters "show data"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a command for your BOT you could refer to link >

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-commands-menu?tabs=desktop%2Cjavascript

You must handle menu commands in your bot code as you handle any message from users. You can handle menu commands in your bot code by parsing out the @Mention portion of the message text. >

```
export class MyBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
constructor()
{
super();
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => { await context.sendActivity(`Echo: '${context.activity.text}'`); await next();
});
}
}
```

You can trigger the function to call the backend API from this handler.